# ¿A santo de qué hago esta pregunta?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

Pues precisamente para preguntar por la expresión «a santo de qué». En el DLE la entrada de santo *nos* ofrece la locución con su significado:

> **[a qué santo,](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XGGB4k6#BLTFvjf)** o **a santo de qué**
>
> 1. locs. advs. Con qué motivo, a fin de qué, con qué pretexto.

La verdad es que la expresión «a qué santo» no lo había oído nunca y la construcción tiene más sentido y si la sustituyo en el título de mi pregunta obtengo:

> ¿A qué santo hago esta pregunta?

La frase me parece más coherente pero sigo sin ver una relación clara con el significado de la expresión.

Para mí además la expresión tiene un matiz como de enfado o hartazgo muchas veces: *¡A santo de qué me cuentas eso!*

¿De dónde viene la expresión?, y ¿qué tiene que ver con los santos?

Comment: +1 por el arte que has tenido poniendo el título de la pregunta. Me pregunto si el origen tendrá algo que ver con el hecho de que hay un santo patrón para cada cosa. Desde santa Rita, patrona de lo imposible, hasta san Pancracio, patrón de la salud y el trabajo. Había también uno a quien rezarle cuando perdías algo. Podría provenir pues de algo así como "a qué santo le tengo que rezar para conseguir tal cosa", pasando por "a qué santo le cuentas eso".

Comment: Tiene pinta de que pueden ir por ahí los tiros. Si es así sigue siendo un poco extraña gramaticalmente la construcción "a santo de qué".

Answer (score 1):

Pues mucho me temo que mi suposición inicial pueda ser errónea (como suele pasar cada vez que postulo respuestas a dedo). El caso es que no he podido encontrar un origen claro de la expresión. A lo más que he llegado es que debe de ser una variante de la expresión *a cuento de*. Me explico...

La expresión "a santo de" aparece repentinamente en textos escritos, más o menos a mediados del siglo XIX. En el CORDE todos los casos son a partir de 1880, aunque en la hemeroteca de la BNE se encuentran casos a partir de 1865, siendo este el primero:

> *¿Y por qué todo? ¿Y á santo de qué este desenfreno?*
>
> La Iberia (Madrid. 1854). 30/9/1865, página 3.

Esto hace que la expresión sea más moderna de lo que me imaginaba en un principio. En el DLE, de hecho, su inserción fue en la edición de 1927:

> **A santo de.** m. adv. Con motivo de, a fin de, con pretexto de.

Curiosamente, esta definición se parece mucho a la de "a cuento de", expresión que sí que lleva en el DLE desde su primera edición de 1729:

> *A cuento.* Modo adverbial. Lo mismo que al caso, a propósito.

De hecho, esta expresión sí que encuentra en la hemeroteca desde antes que la anterior:

> *Creerás, amado lector, que hablo contigo; pero ¿á cuento de qué, no habiéndome preguntado tú nada?*
>
> Minerva o El Revisor general. 1805, página 186.

Lo que me falta por averiguar es por qué "a cuento de qué" mutó en "a santo de qué". Por las fechas, yo diría que se trata de una más de las expresiones que surgieron en Madrid por esa misma época, como hemos visto en otras ocasiones.