# ¿A qué nos referimos al decir "a todas estas"?

Tags: modismos

Siempre he entendido la expresión "a todas estas" como una introducción a una pregunta que de alguna manera sirve para conectarla con el resto de la conversación. Por ejemplo, si estamos conversando sobre política y queremos hacer una pregunta acerca de eso, podríamos decir:

> Y a todas estas ¿a tí cuál partido te gusta?

Otros ejemplos acá:

- [Y a todas estas, ¿por qué le pusieron North?](http://www.univision.com/entretenimiento/celebridades/y-a-todas-estas-por-que-le-pusieron-north-fotos)
- [Y a todas estas, ¿qué ha pasado con Psygnosis?](https://www.vidaextra.com/respuestas/y-a-todas-estas-que-ha-pasado-con-psygnosis)
- [A todas estas ¿Quién tiene la verdad?](https://www.arcoiris.com.co/2016/07/a-todas-estas-quien-tiene-la-verdad/)

  ¿Se entiende esta expresión en todas partes? ¿La frase viene de otra más larga? ¿Qué son acá "todas" y "estas"?

Comment: Puede ser una variante de "[A santo de qué](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22740/5481)" como "Y a (santo de) todas estas (cosas), ¿por qué le pusieron North?"

Comment: Yo uso "a todo esto" exactamente en el mismo contexto y con el mismo significado. Quizás "a todas estas" sea una variante que signifique "a todas estas cosas", como dice @Diego.

Comment: @Diego, pero en la pregunta que colocas de referencia y como colocas en el ejemplo se entiende que "A santo de qué" puede reemplazarse por "por qué". Ese reemplazo no funciona muy bien con "A todas estas ¿Quién tiene la verdad?"

Comment: @MauricioMartinez yo no entiendo "A santo de qué" como equivalente de "por qué" (o que ese sea el único equivalente) si no de "hablando de todas estas cosas" / "ya que ha salido el tema"."A todo esto" y "a todas estas" son locuciones adv. equivalentes ([recogidas en el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZxVCoJq))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el diccionario:

> [**a todo esto**, o **a todas estas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZxVCoJq#C9m55zd)
>
> 1. locs. advs. Mientras tanto, entre tanto.

La verdad es que se me hace rara esta definición, y más viendo tus ejemplos. Para mí significaría más "a propósito".

En todo caso, la expresión parece entenderse bien en todas partes, aunque aquí en España usamos más la variante "a todo esto". La expresión aparece recogida por primera vez en el DLE de 1925 (pensaba que sería más antigua). Ya entonces tenía la misma definición que hoy día, lo que me hace pensar que tal vez esté algo desfasada.

Casos en el CORDE se encuentran desde antiguo, eso sí, con el sentido que le da la RAE:

> *A todo esto mi camarada estava sin sentido; desnudámosle, y mientras llamado un cirujano para que le cobrase, le aplicava varios y precissos remedios [...].*
>
> Gonzalo de Céspedes y Meneses, "Varia fortuna del soldado Píndaro", 1626 (España).

Visto así, sí parece que el uso que se le da en ejemplos como los que propones puedan ser incorrectos, pero supongo que es simplemente la evolución del lenguaje. Hace medio siglo era:

> *A todo esto estava la infanta sobre su palafrén, con tanta alegría de ver muerto a Rolando que no lo podía creer.*
>
> Diego Ortúñez de Calahorra, "Espejo de príncipes y caballeros", 1555 (España).

El origen de la expresión podemos encontrarlo (aunque esto es una suposición) es una antigua fórmula que se usaba ya en el siglo XIII:

> *E yo Pedro Johan, porque ffuy pressente a todo esto de ssuso dicho, escriui este testamento e pus en el mio ssinal en testinoio (sic) de verdaat (sic).*
>
> Anónimo, "Testamento", 1244 (España).

Esta fórmula se usaba para expresar que alguien había sido testigo presencial de algo que había ocurrido (todo lo expresado en el texto previo):

> *Yo Ferrand Péres, escriuano público de Arcos, fuy presente e a todo esto que sobredicho es so testigo.*
>
> Anónimo "Documento de la toma de posesión de Sevilla de la villa de Arcos", 1338 (España).

Fijaos ahora en la sutileza de la siguiente expresión, que queda a medio camino entre la fórmula citada y la expresión tal y como se entiende hoy sería esta:

> *Y a todo esto el Caballero de las Azules Armas estuvo quedo porque bien sentía que su contrario había leído los secretos de su escudo.*
>
> Pedro Hernández de Villaumbrales, "Peregrinación de la vida del hombre", 1552 (España).

Esto se podría entender tanto como "a todo esto fue presente el Caballero, que se mantuvo quedo" como "y mientras sucedía todo esto el Caballero estuvo quedo". De ahí la expresión de "a todo esto" como "mientras tanto".

La variante de la expresión como "a propósito" ignoro cómo surgió, pero lleva ya medio siglo con nosotros al menos:

> *A todo esto, voy a sentarme un poco, porque siento dolor en esta ingle izquierda [...].*
>
> Alfonso Sastre, "M. S. V. (o La sangre y la ceniza)", 1965 (España).

Nótese también que en este último ejemplo la expresión podría sustituirse por "mientras tanto", pero si la entendemos como "a propósito" o como "por cierto" tampoco queda mal. Esta ambigüedad a la hora de usar la expresión puede ser el origen de que poco a poco haya ido variando su significado, y haya dado lugar a ejemplos como los de la pregunta:

> *A todo esto, ¿qué pasa con la poesía del silencio?*
>
> Espéculo. Revista de estudios literarios, 06/2003, "Poesía y posmodernidad".

Otra posible explicación de la variación podría ser que el significado de "mientras tanto" no se refiera a "mientras ocurrían los eventos descritos anteriormente", sino a "mientras decía lo que acabo de decir, se me ha ocurrido esto otro", que sería lo que expresiones como "a propósito" o "por cierto" vienen a significar.

Comment: Me parece muy válida la conexión de los dos significados que haces en el último párrafo. Me pregunto si el DLE tendrá en un futuro una entrada más explícita con el significado de "a propósito" que parece ser el significado que le damos en varias partes.